# Which command is correct in Autosys

Tags: agent, autosys

Which command is correct to check the current job in running status on a specific agent in Autosys

1 ) Autorep -I machine_name | find RU
OR
2 ) Autorep -j ALL - M machine_name | find RU

Answer (score 0):

Below commands returns the list of running job on a particular machine / agent.

```
autorep -M <machine/agent_name> -d
```

example:

```
autorep -M host123@some.com -d
```

Output Columns:

```
JobName | Machine | Status | Load | Priority
```

If executing from linux server, use ***grep, awk*** as per need to reformat the report.